# Skip video in YouTube playlist using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube

I've looked through the [YouTube JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference), but can't find a way to jump to a video in a playlist. (Mimicking the built-in navigation)

And if you're wondering why I'd want both, it's because I have a menu set up with additional information, and want to let the user click these links to jump between the videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own YouTube player script or use this one -- [YouTube JavaScript API Player plus Playlist](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2009/10/youtube-javascript-player-with-playlist.html).

Comment: Wow, that looks pretty neat, man. But I seem to be getting the same problem as one of your commenters: `o.loadVideoById is not a function`... Could it be because I'm running it in an html file that's just on my hard drive?

Comment: Could be for various reasons. Try running it through localhost and keep an eye on JavaScript errors.

Comment: Yeah, running it on localhost solved it. So I guess there are some weird issues with the youtube API running from hard drive, then? Your script's awesome, by the way, just had to do some minor tweaks, and it's pretty much what I was looking for.